# Set all child products to not visible individually

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php

How to set all associated products in the entire store to 'not visible individually' I've been scrolling through other answers but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: You'd need to write a little script that loops through all configurable products, finds their children, loops through each child, sets the visibility, then saves each child. Let me know if you need some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example script that sets the children of both grouped and configurable products to Not Visible Individually.

Save this in ./shell/makechildrennotvisible.php and run from shell.

```
<?php
include_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID );

// Get all configurable and grouped products
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('in' => array('configurable', 'grouped')));

// Loop each configurable product
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    // Get the child products for this product
    if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
        $simpleProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductIds($_product);
    } elseif ($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {
        $simpleProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProductIds($_product);
    }
    printf("Setting children of Product ID %s\r\n", $_product->getId());
    // Loop each child product
    foreach($simpleProducts as $_simpleID) {
        try {
            // Set associated product as not visible
            $_simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_simpleID);
            $_simple->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
            $_simple->save();
            printf("Product ID %s saved as 'Not Visible Individually'\r\n", $_simple->getId());
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            print_r($e);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT (browser version to process 10 products at a time)**

Run this script in the browser as shell/makechildrennotvisible.php?page=1 and increment the page value each time until all products have been procesed. E.g.

www.example.com/shell/makechildrennotvisible.php?page=1
www.example.com/shell/makechildrennotvisible.php?page=2
www.example.com/shell/makechildrennotvisible.php?page=3

```
<?php
include_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID );

// Get the current page from $_GET
$curPage = intval(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('page'));
$curPage = $curPage < 1 ? 1 : $curPage;

// Get all configurable and grouped products
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('in' => array('configurable', 'grouped')))
    ->setPageSize(10);

$curPage = $curPage > $products->getLastPageNumber() ? $products->getLastPageNumber() : $curPage;
$products->setCurPage($curPage);

printf("Processing page %s of %s<br/>", $curPage, $products->getLastPageNumber());

// Loop each configurable product
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    // Get the child products for this product
    if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
        $simpleProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductIds($_product);
    } elseif ($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {
        $simpleProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProductIds($_product);
    }
    printf("Setting children of Product ID %s<br/>", $_product->getId());
    // Loop each child product
    foreach($simpleProducts as $_simpleID) {
        try {
            // Set associated product as not visible
            $_simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_simpleID);
            $_simple->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
            $_simple->save();
            printf("Product ID %s saved as 'Not Visible Individually'<br/>", $_simple->getId());
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            print_r($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated this answer to work with both grouped and configurable products and also to ensure the CurrentStore is set appropriately. Please let me know if it works and accept the answer if it does.

Comment: Hi @bluec I haven't had a chance to run this yet but I have a few questions. Do I need to replace ADMIN_STORE_ID with the appropriate store I'd? Can you run this so it changes all stores products not just the selected store? Also I don't have shell access could I run this through the browser?

Comment: @ZUBU You can leave Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID exactly as it is since without this the product changes won't save. It will already change the visibility of all products from all stores. However, if you have product visibility set differently for different store scopes and wish to override this too then this would need some changes. You could run it in the browser but I don't recommend it. To do so you'd need to move it out of ./shell/ into the root directory and then change `include_once '../app/Mage.php';` to `include_once 'app/Mage.php';`

Comment: I was somewhat successful with the script but the script seemed to stop and not loop through the entire catalog??? Also when I re ran the script it had the exact same output as before i.e. changing the visibility of products it had already changed. I tried clearing cache and reindexing to no avail. So after trying multiple clearing cache etc after running the script for the tenth time it still returns the same as the first time running it. I am running the script through the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok just tried clearing the storage cahce and rerunning and it got about twice as far. Leads me to believe it might be a memory or time out issue???

Comment: Yes, sounds like a memory or timeout issue. It seems like your hosting environment is wholly unsuitable for running Magento (especially no shell access). As a workaround you could process a limited number of products each time the script is executed. I will have to update my answer to show you that.

Comment: Answer updated with version that can process only 10 products at a time to overcome your resource limits.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you @BlueC. There should be an extension for this so less skilled programmers like me can do this in the backend.